# How to make a program use python2.7 instead of default python3.4 on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, python, python-2.7

I am using ubuntu 14.04 and I have a program that depends on python 2.7 and does not support any of python 3.x. Ubuntu 14.04 comes with python3.4 by default. I would like to know if there is a possibility to make my program uses python2.7 instead of the default version. I thought about uninstalling python3.4, but I think it is not a good idea as some other programs may depends on it.

Thanks

Comment: Python 2.7 _is_ the default in 14.04.

Comment: When I type $python it appears python 3.4

Comment: Do you have your python 2.7 installed? So if you run 'python2.7' it gives you the python shell...

Comment: After I installed python2.7 I can get python2.7 shell when I type $python. Before only python3.4 was installed. So can I assume now that a program which depends on python2.7 will run without problems with both versions coexisting?

Comment: Both python versions can coexist at the same time, you just have to call the version you want for your software.

Comment: just read the linked post in reversed direction :)

Comment: Jacob you have right. Depending on shebang defining version, present in python script, the appropriate python version will be used providing it is installed of course.

Comment: Thank you everybody. I am completely ignorant about python, I just want it as a dependency for my target program. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Check your ~/.bashrc and/or .bash_aliases to find if you have any kind of alias like this:

alias python=python3

Change it accordingly to python2.7

Comment: I don't have .bash_aliases file and .bashrc file does not contain an alias for python. Shall I add it?

Comment: You can do it for convenience. Also, do an: 'ls -l /usr/bin/python' to check where it's linked.

Comment: /usr/bin/python links to python2.7. But, what I would like to do is that one program use python while others continue to use python3.4. I assume that when a program depending on python3.4 is executed it will call soft link python3 not python. Is my assumption correct?

Comment: Depends on how it's programmed. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11170827/how-tell-python-script-to-use-particular-version

Answer (score 2):

Normally, in Ubuntu, `python` defaults to `python2`. So you probably have a

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3 
#
```

or similar in the top of your script. Either if this is the case or if you have changed the defaults, in the header of your program, change

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#
```

(or the more probable `python3`) to

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
#
```

In standard Ubuntu, `python` should automatically point to python2:

```
[romano:~/tmp] % ls -l /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 jul 22 09:49 /usr/bin/python -> python2.7
```

so normally the above thing should not be needed. But `python2` and `python3` points respectively to the standard version of version 2 and 3, so if you explicitly want one version, simply tell it.